# Payal nvp vs Paypal Pro?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working for a company that uses paypal nvp for its transactions. I am not sure if these are two completely different things, but if they are, what is the difference? There are so many different paypal account types and API's I am starting to get confused.

If anyone could help me out, it would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NVP API is part of the PayPal Classic API which includes PayPal Payments Pro.  So to integrate Pro you could use NVP or you could use XML/SOAP.